# Can I use loops or lists to reduce the code for this graph?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am plotting a handful of lines on one graph, and I feel like i'm missing a really easy loop or something that would make the code more efficient and easier to read.

An example of what I have is:

```
alphaline = .4
polydegree = 3

#first iteration
xg1 = np.array(df1.query('wealb == "g"')['income'])
yg1 = np.array(df1.query('wealb == "g"')['cont'])
coefg1 = np.polyfit(xg1, yg1,polydegree)
polyg1 = np.poly1d(coefg1)
ysg1 = polyg1(xg1)
ax5.plot(xg1, ysg1, color="#5FB404", label="1", alpha=alphaline)

#second iteration
xg2 = np.array(df2.query('wealb == "g"')['income'])
yg2 = np.array(df2.query('wealb == "g"')['cont'])
coefg2 = np.polyfit(xg2, yg2, polydegree)
polyg2 = np.poly1d(coefg2)
ysg2 = polyg2(xg2)
ax5.plot(xg2, ysg2, color="#31B404", label="2", alpha=alphaline)

#third iteration
xg3 = np.array(df3.query('wealb == "g"')['income'])
yg3 = np.array(df3.query('wealb == "g"')['cont'])
coefg3 = np.polyfit(xg3, yg3, polydegree)
polyg3 = np.poly1d(coefg3)
ysg3 = polyg3(xg3)
ax5.plot(xg3, ysg3, color="#088A08", label="3", alpha=alphaline)
lg1 = plt.legend(title="Children in College")
```

I feel like some sort of `for i in range(3)` would be helpful, but I'm still new to python and couldn't really figure out how to implement. I figured I could have some sort of array for the colors, and then just loop through everything.

I've also been toying with

```
for i in range(len(x)):
  plt.figure()
  plt.plot(x[i],y[i])
```

from [Use a loop to plot n charts Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189488/use-a-loop-to-plot-n-charts-python)

The attempt I have right now looks like:

```
colours = ['r','g','b']
for i in range(3):
    xg[i] = np.array(df[i].query('wealb == "g"')['income'])
    yg[i] = np.array(df[i].query('wealb == "g"')['cont'])
    coefg[i] = np.polyfit(xg[i], yg[i],polydegree)
    polyg[i] = np.poly1d(coefg[i])
    ysg[i] = polyg1(xg[i])
    ax5.plot(xg[i], ysg[i], color=colours[i], label=str[i], alpha=alphaline)
```

Comment: Your final bit of code is what someone would have posted as an answer. Is there a question still in here?

Comment: What's the problem with this last attempt? Can show explain the error?

Comment: When I try that, I receive: `xg[i] = np.array(df1.query('wealb == "g"')['income'])` `NameError: name'xg' is not defined`

Comment: @As3adTintin Asumming that last piece of code is all of it, it has no variable called 'xg' to index. For example, you could create a list that contains three 'None's. 'xg = [None, None, None]'. Assuming this fixes it, just repeat for the rest of the lists.