# Matplotlib and Jupyter Notebooks: new plot outputted per loop iteration

Tags: python, matplotlib

There are a lot of questions regarding how to use matplotlib, especially for how to either update or output a new chart per loop iteration. In particular this question is in relation to matplotlib and jupyter-notebook

For example:

[Use a loop to plot n charts Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189488/use-a-loop-to-plot-n-charts-python)

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19189664/5623899) is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
y=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x[i],y[i])
```

which appears to work...

until we add anything else:

for example, add a sleep statement after each plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep
x=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
y=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x[i],y[i])
    sleep(2)
```

and suddenly it doesn't work.

One can also use any form of print to see the same issue

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep
x=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
y=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x[i],y[i])
    print('loop: ', i)
```

So how can I print out a new plot for each loop in a jupyter-notebook?

Comment: What exactly "does not work"? If running the above, the result is [as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHHoF.png) and four plots are shown.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes, the four plots are made, which is fine. I want them to output during the loop iterations. As it stands, the four plots are rendered after the computation ends

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `plt.pause(1)` after each iteration to tell matplotlib to pause for 1 second and redraw the figures (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pause.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
y=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x[i],y[i])
    plt.pause(1)
```

Now the figures are drawn after each iteration.