# Python only plots last curve in a loop

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, plot, figure

I have a curve that I want to rotate along the z-axis N times in a loop, and each time I want to plot it to the same figure. However I only get the last curve overdrawn multiple times. If instead, I use different figures in every iteration I get the expected result. Where is the mistake? This is the code, the comments are to test creating new figures in each iteration:

```
o = 2*pi/N
for m in range(N):
    #fig = plt.figure()
    #ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    #ax.view_init(45,)
    #fig.set_size_inches(10,10)
    for n in range(len(x1)):
        x1[n],y1[n] = cos(o)*x1[n] - sin(o)*y1[n], sin(o)*x1[n] + cos(o)*y1[n]
    ax.plot(x1,y1,z1,'k')
    #plt.show()
```

This is what I want more or less, that I've achieved using a diferent method:

[image]

but instead i get:

[image]

Here is how I calculate x1,y1,z1 if someone wants to test it

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from numpy import array, linspace
from math import pi, cos, sin, atan2, sqrt

def pltcono(xo,yo,a):
    N = 100
    x1 = []
    y1 = []
    z1 = []
    for t in linspace(0,1,N):
        x = (xo[1]-xo[0])*t + xo[0]
        y = (yo[1]-yo[0])*t + yo[0]
        r = sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
        if (r > 1.0000000001):
            return x1,y1,z1
        o = atan2(y,x)
        x1 += [a*r/(2*pi)*cos(2*pi*o/a)]
        y1 += [a*r/(2*pi)*sin(2*pi*o/a)]
        z1 += [-r*sqrt(1-(a/(2*pi))**2)]
    return x1,y1,z1

def cono(a):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.view_init(45,)
    fig.set_size_inches(10,10)

    o = a/2
    r = 1
    N = 10
    p = a/10

    x = [r*cos(p)]
    y = [r*sin(p)]

    x += [r*sin(o-p)/sin(o)]
    y += [0]
    x1,y1,z1 = pltcono(x,y,a)

    while (o + a < pi):
        o+= a
        x[0] = x[1]*cos(a)
        y[0] = x[1]*sin(a)

        x[1] = r*sin(a/2-p)/sin(o)
        xt,yt,zt = pltcono(x,y,a)
        x1 += xt
        y1 += yt
        z1 += zt

    x[0] = x[1]*cos(a)
    y[0] = x[1]*sin(a)

    x[1] = x[0] - cos(o+a)
    y[1] = y[0] - sin(o+a)
    xt,yt,zt = pltcono(x,y,a)
    x1 += xt
    y1 += yt
    z1 += zt

    x1 = array(x1)
    y1 = array(y1)
    z1 = array(z1)

    o = 2*pi/N
    for m in range(N):
        #fig = plt.figure()
        #ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
        #ax.view_init(45,)
        #fig.set_size_inches(10,10)
        for n in range(len(x1)):
            x1[n],y1[n] = cos(o)*x1[n] - sin(o)*y1[n], sin(o)*x1[n] + cos(o)*y1[n]
        ax.plot(x1,y1,z1,'k')
        #plt.show()


cono(pi/6+pi/24+0.001)
```

Comment: Could you post the values of `x1`, `y1` and `z1`?

Comment: The values, or just how I calculate them? Also, I'm not sure if it is relevant for the question. Do I add it to the quetion?

Comment: No, I just want the values. In order to help you, I need to replicate your problem. And I can't do that without these values.

Comment: You can upload it to google drive or any other cloud service and provide the link

Comment: here is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18bVFJIWfqy3skwUYumJKXWuCORbjqE3H/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1):

Note that you need to create a figure every time or `pyplot` will plot in the first one created.

```py
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

o = 2*pi/N
for m in range(N):
    for n in range(len(x1)):
        x1[n],y1[n] = math.cos(o)*x1[n] - math.sin(o)*y1[n], math.sin(o)*x1[n] + math.cos(o)*y1[n]
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(x1,y1,z1,'k')
```

I assigned random values to `x1`,`y1`,`z1`,`N` and got the following output: 
[image: It is not the whole output, just signifies multiple plots]

It is not the whole output, just signifies multiple plots.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19189664/6224662) for more ways to do the same.

Comment: Maybe I didn't express myself clearly; I do want all the curves in the same plot, in the same figure but somehow it only plots the first curve. If I separate them in diferent figures it works (thats what does the commented code). But it doesnt if it's all of them in the same figure.

Comment: @DPurple can you provide your array values as well so that I can verify my results

Comment: I've added the whole code to the question so you can replicate them. Also there's a link in a comment above with the values I use.

Comment: @DPurple `plotcono` seems to be using some parameter for each element of the array x1,y1and z1. what are those arguments ? can you share the whole code?

Comment: that's the whole code, it should work as is. The main function is cono though; and it gets an angle, preferably one less than pi/2 but I think it should work for any. The last line is the angle I was using. It is an exercise for uni and I was just interested in the plot, that's why the code is a little messy and disorganized