# adress plots in python

Tags: python, matlab, plot

I would like to something I have done in matlab with python:

```
for loop
       fig1 = figure(1)
       plot(d,y);
       hold on
       xlabel('steps[m]');
       ylabel('tips');
       title('Title');
       fig2 = figure(2);
       plot(x,y);
       hold on
       xlabel('steps[m]');
       ylabel('tips');
       title('Title');
```

I would like to switch between multiple plots and modify them (add new lines)
how can I do that?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: if I understand this correctly you will find your solution at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189488/use-a-loop-to-plot-n-charts-python

Comment: which post in the link you mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19189664/3882172 this is the link to the post i meant earlier, If I understand you question right!?